# Android Jetpack - Remove Top Padding of OutlinedTextField with Label

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I've simple OutlinedTextField:

```
OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)),
                    value = enteredTextPassword,
                    onValueChange = { enteredTextPassword = it },
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
                    placeholder = { Text(text = "Password", color = Color.Gray)},
                    singleLine = true,
                    label = { Text("Password", color = Color.Gray) }
                )
```

My outputs are:

- Normal

[image]

- Filled & Focused

[image]

Filled&Focused output is acceptable for me but as you see there is little top padding in Normal output.

Normally, I'm trying to get these outputs:

- Normal

[image]

- Filled&Focused

[image]

How can I remove my top padding on Normal output ? Or, is there anyway to get exact outputs which I mentioned last?

Comment: `OutlinedTextField` is a [material component](https://material.io/components/text-fields#outlined-text-field). And they are designed for the hint label to be on the border.

Comment: @Abhimanyu if there is any other ways to achive outputs that I mentioned last, I dont have to use OutlinedTextField :)

Comment: You can use `BasicTextField` for more customization.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Can you write exact answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple example, you can wrap the `TextField` in a `Box` like this and handle the border color using the `Box`.

This method has a lot of limitations in terms of padding, placement, etc. For more customizations, use a `BasicTextField`

```
@Composable
fun SimpleCustomTextField(
    text: String,
    setText: (text: String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    colors: TextFieldColors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(),
    shape: Shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
) {
    val color: State<Color> = colors.indicatorColor(
        enabled = true,
        isError = false,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
    )

    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(shape)
            .background(White),
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = setText,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                focusedBorderColor = Transparent,
                disabledBorderColor = Transparent,
                errorBorderColor = Transparent,
                unfocusedBorderColor = Transparent,
            ),
            label = label,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(shape)
                .border(
                    width = 1.dp,
                    color = color.value,
                    shape = shape,
                ),
        )
    }
}
```

**Default**

[image: Default]

**Focused**

[image: Focused]

Comment: How would I add just the label animation to a BasicTextField?